# Repace a string in file from a list in python

Tags: python

i am trying to replace text in file from a list in python, but got stuck and need some suggestion.

Basically, i am looking for text in replace_texts in each line of the file then save it using fileinput.

```
replace_texts = ['text 1','text 2']

for line in fileinput.input('file.txt', inplace=True):
    if any(text in line for text in replace_texts):
        # im not sure how to get the value variable from the if**
        replaced_line = line.replace(value, "something else")
        sys.stdout.write(replaced_line)
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

file.txt

```
abctd fdskla fds
text 1 fdlald text 2
fdsa text 2
```

and after run the code above.
file.txt will become

```
abctd fdskla fds
something else fdlald something else
fdsa something else
```

Thanks,

Comment: What's your input file and the expected result? Do you want to split the input lines into words?

Comment: @BuddyBob please see my edit. Thank you

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin please see my edit. Thank you

Comment: so basically, i am looking for text 1, text 2 which is in replace_texts and replace with "something else"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task is straightforward, just loop in the `replace_texts` to try to replace for each target.

The `replace` API will return a modified string, assign it to the `line` variable and continue the loop.

In the last print statement, we directly print the `line` variable, we don't care if it replaced or untouched.

```py
import sys
replace_texts = ['text 1','text 2']

for line in open('file.txt'):
    for target in replace_texts:
        line = line.replace(target, "something else")
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close, it was a good idea to first check if there are `any` occurrences of the word first. The part you were not sure about was, now that you check `True` or `False` for occurrences, if its `True` then you actually loop through your list.

Also if you are actually trying to write to a file, you will either need to use `tempfile` or write to a new file. The example below shows how you can use a context manager to open your old file and outputs a new file with replaced values.

```
replace_text = ['text 1','text 2']

#open the original file and output a new file with replaced values
with open('file 1.txt', 'r') as old, open('file 2.txt', 'w') as new:
    for line in old:
        if any(text in line for text in replace_text):
            #once you confirmed the word is in, then loop through list
            for text in replace_text:
                line = line.replace(text, 'something else')
        new.write(line)
```

**Output in file 2.txt**

```
abctd fdskla fds
something else fdlald something else
fdsa something else
```